# Left align text inside hover box in plotly to make it displayed as whole and not partialy

Tags: r, plotly

I have this plotly chart below which inludes big text. I would like to left align my text in order to make the whole paragraph displayed and make the hover box longer. Or maybe there is a way to adjust it to make it displayed completely.

```
library(plotly)
df2<-structure(list(publicationDate = structure(c(18262, 18262, 18262
), class = "Date"), x = c(10.943317, 11.376795, 11.11172), y = c(5.915477, 
                                                                 7.448679, 6.8502655), z = c(8.941429, 9.370003, 4.6556673), influentialCitationCount = c(65.8153241650295, 
                                                                                                                                                          65.8153241650295, 19.5902329497614), tldr = c("This survey focuses on the detailed representation of the BERT- based technique for word embedding, its architecture, and the importance of this model for pre-training purposes using a large corpus.", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        "This work introduces an algorithm that removes units and layers of a neural network while not changing the output that is produced, which thus implies a lossless compression.", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        "This article aims at addressing this limitation by applying a semiformal boilerplates (BPs) model of functional requirements originally presented in informal natural language to formulate smart grid requirements and demonstrating how functional requirements can be translated to IEC 61499 control codes using MDE to autogenerate an IEC61499 protection and control system with structure and control flow."
                                                                                                                                                          ), title = c("A Multi-layer Bidirectional Transformer Encoder for Pre-trained Word Embedding: A Survey of BERT", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "Lossless Compression of Deep Neural Networks", "Automatic Generation of Control Flow From Requirements for Distributed Smart Grid Automation Control"
                                                                                                                                                          )), row.names = c(472L, 782L, 937L), class = "data.frame")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       




# Create the 3D scatter plot with bolded hover text
scatter3Dplot <- plot_ly(data = df2, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, color = ~publicationDate,
                         type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
                         marker = list(size = 3),
                         text = ~paste("<b>Title:</b> ", title,
                                       "<br><b>Publication Date:</b> ", publicationDate,
                                       "<br><b>Influential Citation Count:</b> ", influentialCitationCount,
                                       "<br><b>TLDR:</b> ", tldr),
                         hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  layout(title = "3D Scatter Plot with Wrapped Title and Custom Popup by Date",
         scene = list(
           xaxis = list(title = "X Axis"),
           yaxis = list(title = "Y Axis"),
           zaxis = list(title = "Z Axis")
         )) %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h"),
         showlegend = FALSE)



scatter3Dplot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58054637/12993861) you could left align the hover text using layout option `hoverlabel = list(align = "left")`. Additionally you could e.g. use `string::str_wrap` to wrap the paragraph and or title.

```
library(plotly)

# Create the 3D scatter plot with bolded hover text
scatter3Dplot <- plot_ly(
  data = df2, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, color = ~publicationDate,
  type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
  marker = list(size = 3),
  text = ~ paste(
    "<b>Title:</b> ", stringr::str_wrap(title, width = 40),
    "<br><b>Publication Date:</b> ", publicationDate,
    "<br><b>Influential Citation Count:</b> ", influentialCitationCount,
    "<br><b>TLDR:</b> ", stringr::str_wrap(tldr, width = 40)
  ),
  hoverinfo = "text"
) %>%
  layout(
    title = "3D Scatter Plot with Wrapped Title and Custom Popup by Date",
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = "X Axis"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Y Axis"),
      zaxis = list(title = "Z Axis")
    )
  ) %>%
  layout(
    legend = list(orientation = "h"),
    showlegend = FALSE,
    hoverlabel = list(align = "left")
  )

scatter3Dplot
```

[image]